# C# Forms Picturebox to show a solid color instead of an image

Tags: c#, windows, image

Im making a little app to display the pictures of guests as they scan their cards.
But i want to to display blank green or red (green if the guest exists without a photo and red if they dont exist)

But i cant figure out how to create a blank colour image.

```
Bitmap bmRed = new Bitmap(imgbox.Width, imgbox.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
imgbox.Image = bmRed;
```

Thats the code i have at the moment and it just makes the box black.
imgbox is a PictureBox

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Don't use an image - set the BackColor property of the PictureBox:

```
imgBox.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

Answer (score 6):

To prevent null pointer exception, create a blank bmp

```
myPicBox.Image = new Bitmap(myPicBox.Width, myPicBox.Height);
Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(myPicBox.Image);

Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Gray);

graphics.FillRectangle(brush, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, myPicBox.Width, myPicBox.Height));
```

Answer (score 2):

How about setting the background color directly?

```
imgbox.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

Answer (score 1):

create a graphics context and draw using it.

```
using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmRed))
{
  g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Red),0,0,imgbox.Width,imgbox.Height);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Single statement:

```
Graphics.FromImage(PicBox.Image=new bitmap(PicBox.Size)).FillRectangle(Brushes.Red,new Rectangle (Point.EMPTY,PicBox.Size));
```

Comment: Sorry I was initially put. PicBox.img instead of PicBox.Image

Comment: Graphics class has no constructor, and if it did, you would still have to dispose of it.  Point.NULL is also wrong.  You had 8 years since the question was asked to test your code.